# how to integrate with Exchange web service in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am working on the development of a web-based application. 
I need to integrate  **MS Exchange** actions into this app, such as sending a mail, creating a private contact, setting up a meeting on behalf of the connected user, etc...
For this purpose, I've identified the package **ews-javascript-api** in github, owned by Gautam Singh.

However, I wasn't able to get started in my own with this package and couldn't find a howto with basic steps. Does anyone have this experience and would be able to get me started?
My environment: Exchange 2010 on premises (yes, that's a bit old). I would be open to setting up a proxy in order to circumvent SOP issues.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/ews-javascript-api which has a basic how-to down the bottom of the page and some sample code. Because that package is a port of Microsoft EWS Managed API most of the samples you will find for the EWS Managed API will work if you just port the syntax to js. Eg a simple bind to the Inbox

```
var ews = require('ews-javascript-api');
var service = new ews.ExchangeService(ews.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new ews.ExchangeCredentials("user", "pass");
service.Url = new ews.Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/Ews/Exchange.asmx"); 
var Inbox = ews.Folder.Bind(service,ews.WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
console.log(Inbox);
```

Comment: Thank you for the hints. In fact I am still struggling with the basic steps, how to connect to the exchange server from browser. Author says the package is compatible with browser usage, but couldn't make it work...

Comment: It should work okay from a browser apart from SO issues, consider when your asking a question to include what errors you get if something doesn't work and the actual code your using which will help anybody trying to answer.